# When is the product of partial derivatives equal to the cross-partial derivative?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, jacobian, hessian-matrix

Given a function taking in two variables defined on some closed subspace of real numbers, when is it true that if we multiply the partial derivatives we get the cross-partial derivative of that function.

That is, when is it true that given given a function $f(x,y)$ we have

$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} =
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x \partial y} $$

If there is no result available that guarantees conditions for equality, are there perhaps conditions under which this expression holds with inequality?

Comment: It's an interesting question, but I'm not sure that it will have a good answer, since (at least physically) this is comparing two very different things. The dimensions on the left don't match the dimensions on the right.

Comment: Make a travelling wave ansatz $f(x,y) = g(x-y) = g(z(x,y))$, I get that $$f = - \ln (c_{1} + y - x) + c_{2}$$ is a solution.